# Selecting a Range with Merge Cells

Tags: vba, excel

So there is a workbook that runs a macro that was made by another group in the company and its GARBAGE but they locked it and wont let me modify the VBA.  So I am trying to pull the output from that workbook into mine.  The headers of the range are in merged rows with the first 11 rows being taken up by the buttons to run the macro.

Here is my current code

```
Sub Pull_Data()
Dim returnValue As Variant
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set wb2 = Application.Workbooks("name.xlsm")
Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("INPUT")
Dim rng As Range
r = Range("H65536").End(xlUp).Row
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Report")
ws.Range("A11:A13").Select
Set rng = ws.Range(Cells(11, 1), Cells(r, 8))
rng.Select
rng.Copy
    wb2.Activate
ws.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(r, 8)).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

End Sub
```

My issue is that when i try to select the entire output it sometimes selects what i want (A11 to H then the last row with value) but sometimes it selects A1:H11 and its frustrating as hell to figure out the issue. If there is a better way I would love to know.

EDIT:

Updated code

```
Sub Pull_Data()
Dim returnValue As Variant
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set wb2 = Application.Workbooks("name.xlsm")
Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("INPUT")
Dim rng As Range
r = Application.Max(Range("H65536").End(xlUp).Row, 11)
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Report")
ws.Range("A11:A13").Select
Set rng = ws.Range(Cells(11, 1), Cells(r, 8))
rng.Select
rng.Copy
    wb2.Activate
ws.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(r, 8)).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

End Sub
```

Comment: If there's no content in ColH then it would select A1:H11. Try `r = Application.Max(Range("H65536").End(xlUp).Row, 11)` instead of what you have now.

Comment: ok so I made your change and I will update my code to reflect the changes.  It worked the very first time but.....then I closed the book and ran the code again and now it only selects the top row so A11:H13 thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
r = Application.Max(Range("H65536").End(xlUp).Row, 11) 'wich sheet is the range assiciated with ?
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Report")
ws.Range("A11:A13").Select 'how is this line usefull at all ?
Set rng = ws.Range(Cells(11, 1), Cells(r, 8)) ' change to  ws.Range(ws.Cells(11, 1), ws.Cells(r, 8))
rng.Select 'delete this line
rng.Copy '
wb2.Activate
ws.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(r, 8)).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll 'change to ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(r, 8)).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```

Comment: I just coming on to post that I think r needs to be specified to a sheet.  As for some of your other questions I put it in there just as a check before I let it blindly copy.  I will post results soon

Answer (score 0):

Rather than pulling data from garbage.xlsm into your workbook, copy the entire worksheet into your workbook.

Then in **your** version of the worksheet, remove the merging, etc.

Comment: My goal is to do it programmaticly so if doing it this way wouldn't that take more steps?

Comment: Perhaps one additional step.......but once the sheet is in **your** workbook, you can manipulate it as you choose.